# IIS Rewrite Module to Sub Folder Directory

Tags: iis, react-router

I have a React SPA published on IIS which is using React Router for URL routes which is working perfectly however within the public directory i have a sub folder that is completely separate to the React project that im trying to access however it doesnt seem to be working:

URL: `http://{REACT_SPA}/Dev` (/Dev is a sub folder)

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
            </rule>

          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

any ideas?

Comment: `<match url=".*" />` <-- Here's your problem. Why are you matching _everything_? (The `IsFile` condition won't let you browse directories, if that's what your aim is)

Comment: **Exactly** where is your `web.config` file located? Are you using any IIS-defined Virtual Directories and/or Application Scopes? (those will be defined in IIS's `applicationHost.config` file)

Comment: @Dai I was matching everything to get react router working on refresh but now i cant access sub folders. Should i be adding a new rule to specifically match ```/dev```?

Comment: @Dai web.config is located in the root of the IIS folder (where my react bundle sits). Its definitely not a virtual directory, let me dig into it however

Comment: Also, exactly what do you mean by "access sub folders"? Are you wanting to use directory-browsing support or not?

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed information, or you can post more details information about your requirement, i will made demo for you.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for not making my question clearer. Essentially, I plan on using the ```dev``` sub folder to host a replica of my react project but in "dev mode" with certain features etc disabled for testing purposes. Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: I still can't understand what you mean, what means `in "dev mode" with certain features etc disabled for testing purposes`?

Comment: @samwu, essentially I want this subfolder to be a completely seperate instance from my main project i.e. ```/Dev``` subfolder will contain a different ```index.html``` file from the root

Comment: This problem seems to have nothing to do with the url rule, the virtual directory is more suitable for your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much @samwu you are very right with a virtual directory setup. Thanks